# There is no dir "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types" with 5.19.0-23-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualization, intel-graphics

I've an issue with `5.19.0-23-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP`, — there is no `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types` dir.

```
uname -a
Linux hp1 5.19.0-23-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 14 15:39:57 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 
ls '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types'
ls: cannot access '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types': No such file or directory

dmesg | grep -i gvt
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/work-ubuntu-22.04-mate/a/@/vmlinuz-5.19.0-23-generic root=ZFS=hp1/work-ubuntu-22.04-mate/a/rootfs ro quiet intel_iommu=on i915.enable_gvt=1 iommu=pt pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction video=efifb:off video=vesa:off vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 kvm.ignore_msrs=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon,nouveau,nvidia,nvidiafb,nvidia-gpu
[    0.106829] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/work-ubuntu-22.04-mate/a/@/vmlinuz-5.19.0-23-generic root=ZFS=hp1/work-ubuntu-22.04-mate/a/rootfs ro quiet intel_iommu=on i915.enable_gvt=1 iommu=pt pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction video=efifb:off video=vesa:off vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 kvm.ignore_msrs=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon,nouveau,nvidia,nvidiafb,nvidia-gpu
[   28.438730] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1505 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/gvt/handlers.c:124 setup_mmio_info.constprop.0+0x9a/0x130 [kvmgt]
[   28.438878]  intel_gvt_setup_mmio_info+0x1c4/0x250 [kvmgt]
[   28.438911]  intel_gvt_init_device+0x111/0x410 [kvmgt]
[   28.438929]  intel_gvt_init_device.part.0+0x10e/0x1b0 [i915]
[   28.439191]  intel_gvt_set_ops+0x98/0xd0 [i915]
```

while with `vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic` everything works fine.

What can be the reason?
How to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist on any of my Ubuntu systems. Why do you think it should exist on yours, and why is it an issue for you if it doesn't?

Comment: @Tilman, this directory will likely to appear if you use next kernel arguments `intel_iommu=on i915.enable_gvt=1 iommu=pt pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction video=efifb:off video=vesa:off vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 kvm.ignore_msrs=1 modprobe.blacklist=radeon,nouveau,nvidia,nvidiafb,nvidia-gpu`.
This directory is needed for GVT to work. I've configured and use GVT to split GPU between host and VMs.
This directory exists with `vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic` kernel, but doesn't exist when I use `5.19.0-23-generic` kernel. So, something has been broken in `5.19.0-23-generic`.

Comment: I see. So your actual issue is that GVT doesn't work anymore after upgrading the kernel. I'm afraid I can't help you with that since I don't use GVT myself, but I suggest you edit your question to that effect to better attract people who can.